# В Yii2 при валидации модели getErrors() возвращает только первые ошибки

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

Имеется форма (`Model`), которая имеет более 1 валидатора на одно поле. По идее, метод `validate()` должен выполнять проверку всеми валидаторами и заносить в свойство `_errors` все найденные ошибки, а не останавливаться после первой ошибки. Это предположение логично следует из того, что в [документации по `getErrors()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getErrors()-detail) показан пример, где возвращается двумерный массив и у атрибута username в примере сразу 2 ошибки. Для возвращения только первых значений есть метод [`getFirstErrors()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#getFirstErrors()-detail), который как раз возвращает одномерный массив по одной ошибке на атрибут. Но непонятно когда же всё-таки `getErrors()` возвращает более 1 ошибки на атрибут и как этого добиться, если понадобится?

Вот тестовый пример. Создаём новый проект Yii2 по advanced шаблону командой `composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced testProject`. Инициализируем командой `init`. Добавляем в него 2 файла.

Тестовая форма в `common/models/TestForm.php`

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class TestForm extends Model
{
    public $fullName;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['fullName', 'required'], // Полное имя не может быть пустым
            ['fullName', 'string', 'min' => 5, 'max' => 100], // Полное имя должно быть строкой от 5 до 100 символов
            ['fullName', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\w+(?:\s+\w+)+$/u'], // Полное имя должно состоять из 2+ слов
        ];
    }
}
```

Тестовый консольный контроллер для проверки в `console/controllers/TestFormController.php`

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use common\models\TestForm;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class TestFormController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($fullName)
    {
        $form = new TestForm();
        $form->fullName = $fullName;
        if ($form->validate()) {
            echo "Form validated successful\n";
        } else {
            echo "Form validated with errors:\n\n";
            var_dump($form->getErrors());
        }
    }
}
```

Выполняем в консоли тест:

```
yii test-form "asd"
```

Получаем результат:

```
Form validated with errors:

array(1) {
  ["fullName"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(47) "Full Name should contain at least 5 characters."
  }
}
```

Хотя переданный параметр "asd" не удовлетворяет сразу 2 валидаторам: "string" и "match". В документации что-то с ходу не нашёл ничего про это.

Comment: Там в документации сказано, что можно передать второй параметр в метод `validate`, который отвечает за очищение предыдущий ошибок. Попробуйте так: `$form->validate(null, false)`.

Comment: @Razzwan, я попробовал -- не помогло. Результат тот же, но я потратил время на изучение кода Yii и разобрался. Второй параметр он отвечает за очистку ошибок, оставшихся с предыдущих вызовов `$form->validate()` или `$form->addError()`. Сейчас напишу сам ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема кроется в том, что валидатор при проверке не выполняет валидацию атрибутов, по которым уже есть накопленные ошибки. Реализовано это в методе `yii\validators\Validator::validateAttributes()`:

```
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    $skip = $this->skipOnError && $model->hasErrors($attribute)
        || $this->skipOnEmpty && $this->isEmpty($model->$attribute);
    if (!$skip) {
        if ($this->when === null || call_user_func($this->when, $model, $attribute)) {
            $this->validateAttribute($model, $attribute);
        }
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода, проверка атрибута не производится, если переменная `$skip` равна `true`. А равна она `true` в 2-х случаях: 1) если свойство валидатора `skipOnError` равно `true` и текущий атрибут имеет ошибки; 2) если свойство `skipOnEmpty` равно `true` и текущий атрибут пуст. У нас выполняется первое условие. Свойство `skipOnError` равно `true` по умолчанию. Поэтому при срабатывании ошибки на первом правиле, остальные правила уже не проверяются. Чтобы решить эту проблему нужно добавить в правила валидации во второй валидатор параметр `'skipOnError' => false`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['fullName', 'required'], // Полное имя не может быть пустым
        ['fullName', 'string', 'min' => 5, 'max' => 100], // Полное имя должно быть строкой от 5 до 100 символов
        ['fullName', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\w+(?:\s+\w+)+$/u', 'skipOnError' => false], // Полное имя должно состоять из 2+ слов
    ];
}
```

Хотя, лично мне кажется не совсем логичным то, что данное поведение жёстко определяется в модели. Это должна быть скорее опция метода `validate()`, поскольку у меня может быть несколько мест использования этой модели. В одном месте мне достаточно только первых ошибок, в другом месте мне нужны все. Что мне для этого две разные модели создавать? Бред какой-то. Впрочем, в Yii подобные нелогичности встречаются часто. :( Чтобы не быть голословным, например, "_csrf" hidden input, который вставляется принудительно из `Html::beginForm()` на основании параметра `enableCsrfValidation` в `Request`. Что лишает меня возможности создавать формы с и без CSRF-токена на одной странице (выход — `Html::beginTag('form')` или голый HTML). Да и непонятно вообще какое отношение имеет Request к рендерингу формы. Простите за это лирическое отступление.